# How to add two integers dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add two integers dynamically with tkinter. My idea is to get the sum after typing in a integer.
My idea:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x100")


v = tk.IntVar()
w = tk.IntVar()

eingabefeld_0 = tk.Entry(master=root, textvariable = v)
eingabefeld_0.place(x=80, y=40)

eingabefeld_1 = tk.Entry(master=root, textvariable = w)
eingabefeld_1.place(x=320, y=40)


label = tk.Label(master=root, textvariable = v)
label.place(x=80, y=80)

label = tk.Label(master=root, textvariable =  str(int(v.get())+int(w.get())))
label.place(x=320, y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

If start the program the result of the addition is not presented in the label. What is missing here?

Comment: You passed something for the `textvariable=` option of your second Label that isn't one of the Tkinter Var types; that simply cannot work.  Even if it did work, you called `.get()` on your two IntVars during the initial startup of your program; the results were the default value of zero, since the user cannot possibly have typed anything in yet.  You need to add a Button with a `command=` function that gets the values from the Entries, adds them, and sets the Label's text to the result.

Comment: I want to do that without a button.

Comment: why do you have your variables `eingabefeld` and `label` being declared multiple times.

Comment: I forgot to give different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the `textvariable` option correct. The value passed to that option needs to be an instance of one of the tkinter variable objects (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc). You can't just pass an expression to it.

You need to write a function that calculates the result and sets the value of this variable. The function can then be called from a button, or you can set a trace on the variable and update it every time the value changes. You'll have to make sure to take care of the case where one of the values you're trying to add is not a valid integer.

For example, start by creating a new variable for the result, and using it in your label. In this case I recommend `StringVar` so that we can display something like "???" if we can't compute the value.

```
resultvar = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(master=root, textvariable = resultvar)
```

Next, create a function that computes the result and stores it in this variable. You need to use try/except since it's possible for the user to delete everything in the entry widget in which case the call to `.get()` will fail.

```
def compute_result():
    try:
        result = v.get() + w.get()
        resultvar.set(result)
    except Exception as e:
        resultvar.set("???")
```

Now you just need to add code that calls this function. You can do it several ways:

- you can bind to the return key so that the result is updated when the user presses that key
- you can bind to any key release so that the result is updated when the user presses and releases any key
- you can add a button that the user has to click to update the value
- you can add a *trace* to the input variables, which will cause a function to be called whenever the values change

To use a trace, call `trace_variable` telling it when to do the trace ("w" means whenever the value is written/changed), and what function to call. The trace will append some arguments to the function that we don't use, so we'll have to change the function to accept these arguments

```
def compute_result(*args):
    try:
        result = v.get() + w.get()
        resultvar.set(result)
    except Exception as e:
        resultvar.set(f"???")
v.trace_add("write", compute_result)
w.trace_add("write", compute_result)
```

With that, whenever the value in the variable `v` or `w` changes, the function will be called and the result variable will be updated.

Comment: I can't use StringVar.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: why not?

Comment: return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Comment: The error is telling you the problem - the variable has an empty string so it can't be converted to a float.

Comment: I still don't get it how to implement this damn code....

Comment: @hallo97: I've updated the answer with some code.

Comment: `trace_variable()` is deprecated, it is suggested to use `trace_add()` instead.

Comment: I used trace("w", compute_result) and it worked fine.